# Auto Completion Ajax laravel

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello I need to do autocompletion to some cities i already have in my db 
so my code is like this :

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="ville" id="ville" class="small" placeholder="Entrer la ville souhaité">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $( "#ville" ).autocomplete({
            source:'{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
            minlength:1,
            autoFocus:true,
            select:function(e,ui)
            {
              $('#ville').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
      });     
      </script>
```

**Controller**

```
class VilleController extends Controller
{
   public function autocomplete(Request $request)
   {
    $term = $request->term;

    $queries = DB::table('ville') 
    ->where('libelle_ville', 'like', '%'.$term.'%') 
    ->take(6)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->libelle_ville]; //you can take custom values as you want
    }
    return response()->json($results);
  }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/autocomplete', array('as' => 'autocomplete', 'uses'=>'VilleController@autocomplete'));
```

It doesn't tells me that I have an error and it doesn't show me any completion either.

Comment: Maybe because `$request->term` is always null. Where does 'term' comes from?

Comment: The request object have only one property and it's term

Comment: First line of your function, do `dd($request->term)` and see whether it contains the string you are inputting.

Comment: And where should I see that ? in the log ?

Comment: ok do `return $request->term` and check your console (Network) part to see if it returns any response. Si t'es sur chrome tu fais click droit -> inspect, puis tu vas dans Network.

Comment: I have a null string from getelementbyid()

Comment: Console is Javascript. No need to change page to see console output. If you could inspect the network tab of your console and see the request, that could help debut. The problem is, we need to find first where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Hi I correct a problem, now I get the json format in localhost:///myController
But I still have no result in the autocompletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stack and EddyTheDove I found out that the error is that aucomplete is not a function so I have to remove the barkets and $function so it would be something like this in the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#ville" ).autocomplete({
            source:'{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
            minlength:1,
            autoFocus:true,
            select:function(e,ui)
            {
              $('#ville').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug json request with laravel is a bit difficult, I recommend you to download this package

https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer

or manually open the laravel log in `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see whats happened